# Syntax for AdvancedFilter function

Tags: excel, vba

I am using Advanced Filter to make a copy of the worksheet `Main Sheet` into another sheet `Editor News` after applying some logical conditions. I am able to do this manually using the UI with the following parameters:

- List range: 'Main Sheet'!$A:$N
- Criteria range: $P$2:$S$4
- Copy to: $A:$N
- Unique records only: unchecked

I would now like to tie this to the `Main Sheet` `Change` event. The documentation isn't very clear on where to specify `List range`, and I tried the following:

```
Private Sub WorkSheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  Debug.Print Target
  Range("'Main Sheet'!A:N").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
     CopyToRange:=Range("'Editor News'!A:N"), _
     CriteriaRange:=Range("'Editor News'!P2:S4"), Unique:=False
End Sub
```

The above results in `Run-time error '1004' Method 'Range of object'_Worksheet failed`.

How do I use `AdvancedFilter` in code?

Comment: Could it be the case, that you have to specify the ranges exactly where you want to filter? Range("'Main Sheet'!A1:N1000")...

Comment: Do you know you can record a macro? This gives you a sample of how the source code should look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't include the sheet name in Range, use Sheets/Worksheets to specify the sheet.

```
Private Sub WorkSheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  Debug.Print Target
  Sheets("Main Sheet").Range("A:N").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
     CopyToRange:=Sheets("Editor News").Range("A:N"), _
     CriteriaRange:=Sheets("Editor News").Range("P2:S4"), Unique:=False
End Sub
```